# $T_{0}$-space in which a limit point of a subset whose neighborhood does not intersect the subset at infinitely many points?

Tags: general-topology

Let me formally ask the question again.

**Question.** Is there a $T_{0}$-space that has a subset $A \subseteq X$ that has the folloing property?

There exists $p \in X$, a limit point of $A$ such that there is a neighborhood of $p$ intersects $A$ at finitely many points.

Note that there is no such subset $A$ in $T_{1}$ space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: the [Sierpiński space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) is a simple example.

This is the set $\{0,1\}$ with the topology $\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$; $0$ is a limit point of $\{1\}$.

Comment: Oh gee. I came up with the same example but somehow thought that I had to check for all the neighborhoods. Thanks, now I even know the name of the example!